# Proving that an isotopy of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ must preserve orientation of an embedded circle.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Consider two very simple maps from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to itself: the identity $I(x,y) = (x,y)$ and a reflection about the $y$-axis: $R_{y}(x,y) = (-x,y)$. For any embedded circle, $S^{1} =  \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}, with \  x^{2} + y^{2} = r^{2} \}$, $I$ obviously *preserves* the orientation of of $S^{1}$ and $R_{y}$ *reverses* the orientation of $S^{1}$.

Using the fact that fundamental group of both $\mathbb{R}^{2} - (0,0)$ and $S^{1}$ is isomorphic to $
\mathbb{Z}$, we can show that $I$ and $R_{y}$ are *not homotopic* in $\mathbb{R}^{2} - (0,0)$; let $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2} - (0,0)$, defined by $\gamma(t) = (\cos(2\pi t), \sin(2\pi t))$, be the *counterclockwise* circle of radius $1$, and let $[\gamma]$ denote its homotopy equivalence class in $\mathbb{R}^{2} - (0,0)$. Since $R_{y} \circ \gamma$ will be a *clockwise* loop in $\mathbb{R}^{2} - (0,0)$, $[R_{y} \circ \gamma] \neq [I \circ \gamma] = [\gamma]$. Since homotopies necessarily preserve the equivalence classes of loops, it follows that there is no homotopy from $I$ to $R_{y}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2} - (0,0)$. I realize this proof was somewhat hand-wavy; it relied on the fact that there were two distinct generators (clockwise and counterclockwise) for the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}^{2} - (0,0)$, and I did not prove this rigorously.

Transitioning from the space $\mathbb{R}^{2} - (0,0)$ to whole space $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, it is clear that $I$ and $R_{y}$ are then *homotopic* ; just consider $H_{t}(x,y) = ((1-2t)x, y)$; $H_{0} = I$ and $H_{1} = R_{y}$. However, how can it be proven that there is *no isotopy*, that is a homotopy $H: \mathbb{R}^{2} \times [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ in which each $H_{t}$ is a *homeomorphism* from $I$ to $R_{y}$? Notice that I am not requiring that this isotopy be *smooth* as otherwise we could employ the use of differential forms and show that orientation must be preserved. Is there some topological invariant that an isotopy must preserve that that homotopy does not have to? My thoughts so far are that for the unit disk $D = \{ x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 1 \}$, the image $H_{t}(D)$ must always be homeomorphic to a disk if $H$ is an isotopy. Perhaps we could choose a path in the interior of $D$, $\eta: [0, 1] \rightarrow \{ x^{2} + y^{2} < 1 \}$ such that $\eta(t)$ always lives in the interior of $H_{t}(D)$. In this case, $H(D - \eta([0,1]))$ should be homeomorphic to $D - [-
\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$. The fundamental group of $D - [-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$ is identical to that of $D - (0,0)$ and $S^{1}$ (the integers $\mathbb{Z}$). Could we maybe use this to exclude the possibility of an isotopy from $I$ to $R_{y}$ since such a map would have continuously deform a counterclockwise loop in $H(D - \eta([0,1]))$ to a clockwise one? I know I am missing the details, but any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Note that *there is* an isotopy from $I$ to $R_{y}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$; simply let $H_{t} = R_{y}(\pi * t)$, where $R_{y}(\alpha)$ is a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ about the $y$-axis through angle $\alpha$. Then, $H: \mathbb{R}^{3} \times [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$ with $H_{0} = I$ and $H_{1} = R_{y}$.

Comment: Do you know homology theory? The trick is to work with $H_2$ of the Riemann sphere, the 1-point compactification of the plane.

Comment: I read that homology groups can be used to define orientation. I also know that the Riemann Sphere is the one-point compactification of the plane, but I am not super familiar with the details.

Comment: Do you know what the 2nd homology group of the Riemann sphere is? Can you compute the action of the reflection on this group?

Comment: I believe the 2nd homology group of the Riemann Sphere is just the integers (intuitively, this is because the sphere has one two dimensional "hole"). I believe that the reflection should simply switch the generators, i.e. send the generator associated with $1$ to the generator associated with $-1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Do you know that homotopic maps induce the same homomorphisms of homology groups? If you do, you should be able to finish the proof on your own.

Comment: That seems reasonable, given that homology groups, like homotopy groups, should be homotopy invariant. I do see how to finish the proof once this is established. Are there any details I am missing from showing that homotopic maps induce the same homomorphims of homology?

Comment: Well, at this point you do not really know how to prove that homotopy induces the same maps. You will find a proof in any AT book (Hatcher, Massey,...). My suggestion is to spend some time learning this material systematically.

Comment: an approach in the spirit of your 2nd paragraph: focus your attention on the image of the unit circle under the purported isotopy $H$. I.e. the winding number $n\big(H_t\circ \gamma, H_t(0)\big)$ is well defined for all $t\in [0,1]$ (injectivity) and is $1$ when $t = 0$ and is $-1$ when $t=1$ so e.g. attack $T := \sup \big\{t: n(H_t\circ \gamma, H_t(0))=1\big\}$ and $w:= H_T(0)$.  For reasons of compactness the winding number $n\big(H_t\circ \gamma, w\big)$ is well defined for $t\in [T-\delta , T+ \delta]$ for $\delta \gt 0$ small enough, yet is not homotopy invariant, a contradiction.

Comment: How would this change if $H_{t}$ were just a homotopy instead of an isotopy. Would the winding number $n(H_{t} \circ \gamma, H_{t}(0))$ still be defined be well defined for all $t \in [0, 1]$, but the winding number $n(H_{t} \circ \gamma, w)$ no longer need be defined in $[T - \delta, T+ \delta]$?

Comment: In the second paragraph, my homotopy at $t = \frac{1}{2}$, $H_{\frac{1}{2}}$ would send the entire unit circle to the line segment, $-1 \leq y \leq 1$ living on the $y$-axis, so the winding number, $n(H_{\frac{1}{2}} \circ \gamma, H_{t}(0)))$ would no longer be defined (I think) since $H_{\frac{1}{2}} \circ \gamma$ is no longer a loop. Is this correct?

Comment: I somewhat follow the reasoning; $H_{t} \circ \gamma$ should NOT INTERSECT $w = H_{T}(0)$ for $t \ in [T - \delta, T+ \delta]$ by some compactness argument about homeomorphisms. However, how do we know that $n(H_{T+ \delta} \circ \gamma, w)$ is not 1? $H_{T}$ did not move to become $H_{T + \delta}$. I think I am just missing how to fill in some of the details.

Comment: @Robert when responding to someone in comments in general you need to tag them. (Exception: when there is only one other person in comments).The tag isn't needed for messages to you since OP always gets notified. For 1st question, no-- the point is $0$ and a point on unit circle cannot be equal under an injective map but once you discard injectivity (/isotopy) requirement, then they can be equal and the winding number might not be well defined. For 2nd comment I don't follow what homotopy you are referring to (and using $H$ to denote both homotopy and isotopy is getting hard to follow).

Comment: For 3rd comment: one approach is there's an $\epsilon \gt 0$ distance between $w$ and all points on the image of the curve $H_T\circ \gamma$, which I denote as $[H_T\circ \gamma]$.  Wielding uniform continuity select $\delta$ such that all point on the curve move by at most $\frac{\epsilon}{4}$ and $\vert H_{T+\delta}(0)-w\vert \lt\frac{\epsilon}{4}$. Then $w$ and $H_{T+\delta}(0)$ are path connected in $\mathbb R^2-[H_{T+\delta}\circ \gamma]$ so $n\big(H_{T+ \delta} \circ \gamma, w\big)=n\big(H_{T+ \delta} \circ \gamma, H_{T+\delta}(0)\big)\neq 1$

Comment: @user8675309. That seems reasonable - if one can show that $n(H_{T+\delta} \circ \gamma, w) = n(H_{T + \delta} \circ \gamma, H_{T + \delta}(0)) \neq 1$, then we get a contradiction since $n(H_{t} \circ \gamma, w)$ should be invariant under a homotopy in $[T - \delta, T+ \delta]$.

Comment: @user8675309, for the second comment, I was referring to the homotopy that I defined in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ between $I$ and $R_{y}$: $H_{t}(x, y) = ((1-2t)x, y)$.

Comment: Also, do we know for certain that $n(H_{T}(\gamma), w) = 1$? This is obviously true if the supremum lives in the set $\{ t : n(H_{t} \circ \gamma, H_{t}(0)) = 1 \}$, but I don't know why this should necessarily be true.

Comment: Also, I think we only need $|H_{T + \delta}(0) - w| < \epsilon$; that way $H_{T+\delta}(0)$ lives in the epsilon ball $B_{\epsilon}(w)$ and so there must be a path in $\mathbb{R}^{2} - H_{T + \delta}(\gamma)$ between $w$ and $H_{T + \delta}(0)$ since all points on $H_{T + \delta} \circ \gamma$ must be at least $\epsilon$ away from $w$.

Comment: Last two comments were for @user8675309.

Comment: re the supremum: There is a (possibly constant) sequence $t_k \leq T$ such that $t_k\to T \implies$ some $t_{k'} \in [T-\delta , T]$ for any $\delta \gt 0$ but my prior comment tells us $n\big(H_{t'} \circ \gamma, w\big)=n\big(H_{t'} \circ \gamma, H_{t'}(0)\big)$ for any $t'\in [T-\delta , T+ \delta]$ by selecting small enough $\delta$ so $n\big(H_{t_{k'}} \circ \gamma, w\big)=1$.  The idea is you should be able to visualize all this and use compactness to make it rigorous; my argument has a strong analytic flavor and I am getting the sense that you don't have the analysis background for it.

Comment: @user8675309; Thank you for the clarification; if $\delta$ is small enough, $w$ and $H_{t'}(0)$ should live in the same path-connected component of the image of $H_{t'} \circ \gamma$, $[H_{t'} \circ \gamma]$ and then conclude that $n(H_{t'} \circ \gamma, w)  = n(H_{t'} \circ \gamma, H_{t'}(0))$.